# Invalid service "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager": its constructor must be public

Tags: symfony4

I've added "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" as service and with public visibility:

[image]

but I got this error:

[image]

I want to inject EntityManager in my controllers. What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you inject EntityManager in Controller ? and you can call EntityManager from Controller wherever.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error **""Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager": its constructor must be public."**, because by default symfony tries to create the service using its name as the class and calling its constructor if no factory defined. [Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager:__construct is protected](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method___construct), so you **cannot use new EntityManager** outside of this class or only from a class extending it.

You should use the [create factory method](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html#method_create) and provide its arguments:

```
parameters:
    doctrine.orm.entitymanager.factory: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager

services:
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
        factory:   ["%doctrine.orm.entitymanager.factory%", "create"]
        arguments:
             $connection: "provide the connection also here"
             $config: "provide the config also here"
        public: true
```

Line **class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager** is not needed in this case, class will default to the service name if omitted.

You will have to define the factory arguments($connection & config) as services also and provide them to the factory.

PS: I do not know what you are trying to do, but maybe what you are seeking can already be done using the [Doctrine Bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle)